# Casus in »Er satzte sich bei die Knechte.«

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context, grammatical-case, history

Ich habe schon wieder eine Frage zu dem knapp 300 Jahre alten Text der Matthäuspassion von J.S.Bach:

In der Nr. 31 dieses Musikstücks singt der Evangelist diesen Text:

> Die aber Jesum gegriffen hatten, führeten ihn zu dem Hohenpriester Kaiphas, da nun die Schriftgelehrten und Ältesten sich versammlet hatten. Petrus aber folgete ihm nach von ferne bis in den Palast des Hohenpriesters und ging hinein und **satzte sich *bei die* Knechte**, auf daß er sähe, wo es hinaus wollte. [...]

Dieser Text steht genau so in meinen Noten (Bärenreiter Urtext), im [Online-Textbuch der Matthäus-Passion](http://opera.stanford.edu/iu/bachlib/BWV244.HTM), und auch in den Ausgaben anderer Verlage. Somit ist ein Fehler eigentlich auszuschließen. In modernem Deutsch würde dieser Text ungefähr so lauten:

> Jene, die Jesus ergriffen hatten, führten ihn zu dem Hohenpriester Kaiphas, wo sich nun die Schriftgelehrten und Ältesten versammelt hatten. Petrus folgte ihm aber von ferne bis in den Palast des Hohenpriesters nach und ging hinein und **setzte sich *zu den* Knechten**, um zu sehen, was da vor ging.  [...]

Mich irritiert die Formulierung »*bei die*« in »[er] satzte sich *bei die* Knechte«.

Soll das heißen (wie in meiner obigen »Übersetzung«):

> Er setzte sich **zu** den Knechten. (Wohin?)

Oder eher wirklich so wie es in der Partitur steht:

> Er setzte sich **bei** den Knechten. (Wo?)

In beiden Fällen steht im modernen Deutsch »den Knechten« im Dativ. Im Original steht aber »die Knechte«, was ich als Akkusativ interpretiere, denn der Nominativ erscheint mir noch unpassender.

Handelt es sich im Original wirklich um einen Akkusativ? Wenn ja, wie ist die Aussage »Er satzte sich bei die Knechte« zu interpretieren?

Oder handelt es sich doch um einen Dativ, so wie auch in Bairischen Dialekten:

> (Steirisch:)
>   a) »Er håt si zu di Knecht zuwighukt.« (wörtlich: »Er hat sich zu den Knechten dazugehockt«)
>   b) »Er håt si bei di Knecht hiighukt.« (wörtlich: »Er hat sich bei den Knechten hingehockt«)

<sub>(Das mudartliche »hukn« stammt zwar von »hocken« ab, wird aber in der Bedeutung von »sitzen« verwendet.)</sub>

Besteht dieser Zusammenhang zwischen der sächsischen Hochsprache des 18. Jahrhunderts mit modernen bairischen Dialekten? Wenn ja, Wie ist das zu erklären?

Comment: Klingt ein bisschen wie _Butter bei die Fische_ oder auch _Schackeline, komma bei die Omma!_

Comment: @Crissov: War das nicht »Schackeline, geh wech von die Regale, du Arsch!«?

Comment: @Crissov & Wrzlprmft: Wovon bitte redet ihr? In welcher Gegend sagt man »bei die Fische« oder »bei die Oma?« Hingegen kenne ich »geh weg von die Regale/Fenster/...« denn das sagt man im Osten Österreichs auch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Also ich kann mir *bei die Fische* sehr gut auch in Österreich vorstellen.

Comment: "Ich geh auf den Bus und fahr bei mein Omma" kenne ich von Verwandten aus dem Ruhrpott, mit Ostrpreußischen Wurzeln.

Comment: _Butter bei die Fische_ ist eine feste Wendung mit m.W. bzgl. des Kasus nicht ganz geklärten nord-/plattdeutschen Wurzeln (dürfte original _bi de Fisch_ sein). Sie dürfte inzwischen bundesweit verbreitet sein und heißt so viel wie ‚Klartext reden‘ oder ‚zur Sache kommen‘. Der andere Fall ist mit Rheinland/Ruhrgebiet oder allgemeiner Unterschicht assoziiert; _komma (= komm mal) bei mich bei_ ist auch ein typisches anekdotisches Beispiel dafür.

Comment: Maasumi: Vorstellen kann man sich viel, aber ich habe das noch nie gehört. Es klingt jedenfalls für mich extrem deutsch (im Sinn von nicht-österreichisch).

Comment: In der verwandten Frage [»bei« + Akkusativ statt Dativ (z.B. »Butter bei die Fische«)](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31122/bei-akkusativ-statt-dativ-z-b-butter-bei-die-fische) habe ich jetzt gefragt, ob `bei` früher vielleicht als Wechselpräposition benutzt wurde.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der gleiche Text in Matthäus 26 lautet in einer Bibel von 1912

> Petrus aber folgte ihm nach von ferne bis in den Palast des Hohenpriesters und ging hinein und setzte sich zu den Knechten, auf daß er sähe, wo es hinaus wollte.

Heute heißt die gleiche Stelle

> Petrus folgte Jesus von weitem bis zum Hof des hohepriesterlichen Palastes; er ging in den Hof hinein und setzte sich zu den Dienern, um zu sehen, wie alles ausgehen würde.

Und in der Originalübersetzung von 1545 steht

> Petrus aber folgete jm nach von ferns / bis in den Pallast des Hohenpriesters / vnd gieng hin ein / vnd satzte sich bey die Knechte / Auff das er sehe / wo es hinaus wolte.

Von der Verwendung des Akkusativs mit *bei* ist im Ausdruck "Jetzt mal Butter bei die Fische" ja auch noch ein anderes Überbleibsel geblieben.

Die Herren Grimm erlauben in ihrem Wörterbuch noch *sowohl* Akkusativ als auch Dativ, wobei der Akkusativ wohl "darauf zu" statt "in Ruhe bei" bedeutete.

> Bei, die praeposition.
>   an ist gerecht für den acc. wie den dat., nachdem es nahen oder bleiben (bewegung oder ruhe) ausdrückt. auch bei regiert beide casus, zu hingegen für nahen oder bleiben allein den dat. statt des bei der ruhe hatte die alte sprache oft den instrumentalis.

Wann genau der Akkusativ mit *bei* der Sprache verlorengegangen ist, kann man damit natürlich nicht sagen, zu Grimms Zeiten (ca. 1850) war er jedenfalls noch erlaubt, die Bibel von 1912 verwendet schon "zu".

Comment: Interessant. Warum auch sollte “bei” nicht ebenso wir “in”, “neben” etc. je nach Kontext Akkusativ oder Dativ erlauben?

Comment: Sieh an. "mit Akkusativ, nicht standardsprachlich. *Komm mal bei mich bei*". Was es nicht alles in den Duden schafft?

Comment: ich meinte nur, dass ich keinen systematischen Grund sehe. Ein Lernender wird vielleicht auch, nachdem er „ich stellte mich vor die Knechte“, „ich stehe vor den Knechten“ ebenso „ich setzte mich bei die Knechte“, „ich sitze bei den Knechten“ erlauben. Dass die Grammatik momentan nicht so ist, ist mir schon klar. Die Frage war rhetorisch als Bemerkung gemeint.

Comment: Achso. Immerhin hat sie mich zum Nachschauen gebracht ;) . Interessant ist, dass der Akkusativ tatsächlich (auch) im Duden steht - vor allem mit einer so oberschrägen Formulierung. Wusste ich vor deiner Frage nicht. Aber systematische Gründe für einen bestimmten Kasus, vor allem bei Präpositionen zu suchen, dürfte müßig sein. Daran bin ich schon bei Latein verzweifelt....

Comment: Das könnte sogar den »bairischen Dativ« erklären … Schöne Antwort!