# »bei« + Akkusativ statt Dativ (z.B. »Butter bei die Fische«)

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

Die Präposition `bei` regiert den Dativ und gilt nicht als Wechselpräposition. (Siehe z.B. [Prepositions and Postpositions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Prepositions_and_Postpositions) auf Wikibooks.) Allerdings gibt es auch heute noch die Redewendung »[Butter bei die Fische](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Butter%20bei%20die%20Fische&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)«.

Bei + Akkusativ kenne ich sonst nur aus dem Satz »[Er] satzte sich bei die Knechte« aus der Matthäuspassion.

Gibt es heute noch andere **Redewendungen** mit `bei` + Akkusativ?

(In der Frage über »[[Er] satzte sich bei die Knechte](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28587/casus-in-er-satzte-sich-bei-die-knechte)« ging es eher um eine alternative Formulierung, z.B. mit `zu` statt `bei`, und den Zusammenhang mit bestimmten Dialekten.)

**Update**: Ist `bei die Fische` vielleicht ein Beispiel von einem veralteten Gebrauch von `bei` als [Wechselpräposition](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/praepositionen/praepositionen-mit-akkusativ-oder-dativ-wechselpraepositionen/)? (Cf. "Ich habe die Tasche vor *die* Tür gestellt. Die Tasche steht jetzt vor *der* Tür.")

Comment: "Isch geh bei Aldi"; "ZU Aldi" - "Watt, schon halb sieben?" - Funktioniert nicht mehr seit der Änderung des Ladenschlusses.

Comment: Ich hätte das für Nominativ gehalten. Woraus kann man auf  Akkusativ schließen?

Comment: @guidot Ich habe noch nie von Präpositionen mit dem Nominativ gehört. Hat es früher solche Präpositionen gegeben?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Ich rechne das Beispiel mit den Fischen in dieselbe Kategorie wie *Tu mal die Oma winken* -  das klappt auch ganz ohne Präposition.

Comment: @guidot Ist `die Oma` in `Tu mal die Oma winken` denn kein **Akkusativobjekt ohne Präposition**? Ähnlich wie `dich` in `Darf ich dich etwas fragen?`?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Natürlich nicht. Wenn, dann wäre es ein Dativobjekt - zumindest mit korrektem Artikel (`[…] der Oma winken.` → Wem oder was?). Durch einen falschen Artikel wird es natürlich nicht zum Nominativ, sondern eben zu einem Dativobjekt mit falschem Artikel :D.

Comment: Ich habe "Butter bei die Fische" bislang für Mundart gehalten. Ein Textfragment aus der Matthäuspassion könnte dagegen schlicht veraltet sein.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe jo, *die Fische* ist Nominativ. Mit Akkusativ wäre es *Butter bei den Fischen.* Was mit *Tu mal...* allerdings ganz arg daneben klingt. ^^

Comment: @queuverflow "bei" + Nominativ?? Wie gesagt, ich habe noch nie von Präposition mit Nominativ gehört. Auch semantisch macht der Nominativ keinen Sinn, da "die Fische" hier doch kein Subjekt ist?

Comment: @DominikGeorge Ist im Satz "Sie fragten den Lehrer, wie er die Leistung des Schülers einschätzt." `den Lehrer` ein Dativobjekt mit falschem Artikel? Ist `fragen` + Akkusativ für Personen denn falsch? Um auf die ursprüngliche Frage zurückzukommen: Ist `bei die Fische` vielleicht ein Beispiel von einem veralteten Gebrauch von `bei` als Wechselpräposition? (Cf. "Ich habe die Tasche vor *die* Tür gestellt. Die Tasche steht jetzt vor *der* Tür.")

Comment: Natürlich macht der Nominativ dort keinen Sinn, denn er steht dort falsch. Das ist genau der Punkt ;-)

Comment: @queuverflow: "Mit Akkusativ wäre es *Butter bei den Fischen.*" - das wage ich aber zu bezweifeln. Wen oder was brate ich mir zum Abendessen? - Den Fischen?! Nein, der Akkusativ von *die Fische* lautet natürlich genau wie der Nominativ *die Fische*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ups, korrekt. Da hab ich das Beispiel *Tu mal die Oma winken* als Akkusativobjekt innerlich übenommen. Wäre natürlich Dativ richtig. Nominativ aber immernoch nicht.

Comment: Zwar ohne „bei”, aber auch irgendwie anders als erwartet: „Bis die Tage!”

Answer (score 4):

Im Hessischen ist das Teil des Dialekts. Hier hört man öfter Dinge wie

> Komm mal bei die Oma.
>   Ich geh mal bei die REWE.

Als Wahlhesse finde ich das aus zwei Gründen fürchterlich:

1. "Bei" bestimmt in meinem Verständnis einen Ort und keine Richtung.
2. Sowohl "bei" als auch "zu(r)" stehen mit Dativ.

Die Matthäuspassion wurde 1727 uraufgeführt, der Text ist vermutlich sogar älter. Zu dieser Zeit gab es noch kein einheitliches "Hochdeutsch", was es wahrscheinlich macht, dass hier eine starke Dialektfärbung vorliegt.

Bezüglich "Butter bei die Fische" schreibt Crissov in einem Kommentar [zu der von Dir verlinkten Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28587/casus-in-er-satzte-sich-bei-die-knechte):

> *Butter bei die Fische* ist eine feste Wendung mit m.W. bzgl. des Kasus nicht ganz geklärten nord-/plattdeutschen Wurzeln (dürfte original *bi de Fisch* sein).

Das scheint mir nicht abwegig und würde bedeuten, dass sich ein ursprünglicher Dialektausdruck verbreitet hat und - eventuell auch aufgrund von Missverständnissen - diese seltsame Grammatik erhalten hat.

Tofro zitiert in seiner Antwort auf dieselbe Frage:

> Die Herren Grimm erlauben in ihrem Wörterbuch noch sowohl Akkusativ als auch Dativ, wobei der Akkusativ wohl "darauf zu" statt "in Ruhe bei" bedeutete.
>   *Bei, die praeposition. an ist gerecht für den acc. wie den dat., nachdem es nahen oder bleiben (bewegung oder ruhe) ausdrückt. auch bei regiert beide casus, zu hingegen für nahen oder bleiben allein den dat. statt des bei der ruhe hatte die alte sprache oft den instrumentalis.*

Das würde dann, auch wenn's mich schmerzt, das hessische *Komm mal bei die Oma* rechtfertigen...

Comment: Interessant. Ich hätte die genannten Beispiele gefühlsmäßig eher mit dem Dialekt aus Köln als dem aus Hessen in Verbindung gebracht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich auch, aber man findet das verbreitet auch hier in Mittelhessen...

Answer (score 3):

Ja,

> Butter bei die Fische

ist ziemlich sicher ein Überbleibsel einer früheren Verwendung von "bei" als *Wechselpräposition*. Die damalige Verwendung (auch in dem Bibelzitat) entspricht dem in allen Kriterien.

1. Verwendung mit Dativ zur *Angabe einer Lage oder Bewegung in einem definierten Bereich*
2. Verwendung mit Akkusativ zur Angabe einer *Bewegung auf etwas zu*

Es gibt auch noch einige zusammengesetzte Verben, die diese These möglicherweise unterstützen:

> Jeder muss sein Scherflein zum Gemeinwohl beisteuern

braucht ein zusätzliches "zu", um den Dativ zu rechtfertigen.

> Jeder muß sein Scherflein *dem* Gemeinwohl beisteuern

hört sich für mich sehr komisch an.

Comment: Schade, dass Du dafür keine Quellen hattest.

Comment: Never mind, die andere Frage hat mehr Information.

Answer (score -2):

Sage ich selbst eher weniger. Aber:

> Komm mal vorbei.

Ist normales Deutsch. Genauso wie **Beischlaf**

**Bei** ist einfach nur ein Wort, wie an, oder daneben.

Wenn ich den Satz. "Butter bei die Fische" analysiere. Dann sehe ich 2 B's hintereinander. Und ich finde "Butter bei" ist einfacher zu sprechen als "Butter an" wegen der Öffnung des Mundes beim "A".

Einfache Energiekonservierung.

Comment: Ich seh nicht, was "Beischlaf" (oder Beistrich oder sonst ein Wort, das mit "Bei" anfängt) mit dem Thema zu tun hat. Das Energiesparen (Wie packt man denn Energie in Konserven? In Form von Kalorien?) halte ich für Blödsinn, bis Du belegst, dass man für verschiedene Buchstaben verschieden viel Energie verbraucht. Letztlich sind Wörter, die mit dem gleichen Buchstaben anfangen, ein beliebtes Mittel in der Werbung (Alliteration), und das würde keiner machen, wenn es schwer zu sprechen wäre.

Answer (score -2):

Meines Wissen liegen solche "grammatische Fehlern" an dem Dialekt oder der Umgangssprache in sich.

Etwas Ähnliches passiert z. B. in Süddeutschland, wo man sagt:

> Wegen dem Geld

oder

> Wegen dem Wetter